# heroku - I don't want to install postgres locally!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler

Maybe I am missing something obvious here, but, I am developing an app that for now we want to run on heroku. I develop using mysql. I don't have, or want, to install postgres on my machine here.

I have this in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2', '~>0.2.6', :group => :development
gem "pg", :group => :production
```

Yet, when I do a bundle install on my local machine - in development - I see this:

```
Installing pg (0.11.0) with native extensions /Users/smyp/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:533:in `build_extensions': ERROR:   Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

/Users/smyp/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
--with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

Which is what I would expect as I don't have postgres locally... but why is it trying to install it?! Doesn't this defeat the purpose of groups?

Comment: What's wrong with Postgres? I installed it on my machine and it was pretty easy.

Comment: That is not really the point of the question (though I much prefer mysql and don't see the need to have 2 databases on my machine).

Comment: I'm working with a designer and getting a Rails app running on sqlite3 is a lot simpler. No need to put her through the hassle of installing pg (though it's not that bad, it's still extra command-line work)

Answer (score 16):

Use `bundle install --without production`

Comment: Thanks - so indeed I was missing something obvious! It seems a bit silly to me that this is the way it is done, but c'est la vie.

Comment: The whole point of bundler it to replicate your development and production environments with the minimum fuss. I would suggest you do install postgres on your development machine to avoid sql errors in production. If you're using osx using homebrew it is utterly trivil. With most modern linux package management equally so. Windows I don't know.

Comment: It's typically fine if you don't wander too far from the track and just stick to activerecord queries but as soon as you start doing findbysql then you need to be using the db platform you're application will be deployed on. Also if you use some gems you need to be careful, I used one of acts_as_taggable gems, worked great locally, failed miserably on Heroku since it had platform specific SQL in it.

Comment: Also unless you're using the new Heroku Cedar stack you don't need to specify pg in your gemfile since Heroku will inject that for you when you deploy your application.

Comment: It's not just `find_by_sql` that will give you trouble. Postgres does case-sensitive queries; mysql is case-insensitive. `group by` queries work differently. Etc. I find that discovering these differences in staging or production is far more painful than installing and using Postgres on my dev machine (a Mac).

Comment: All good points. Heroku is a temporary destination for us, we will be moving to our usual platform of EC2 (where we have Ubuntu and mysql). I know of the differences... another one is that postgres does boolean as true and false, not 1 and 0! I have to say that I have been using meta_where and meta_search for quite a while and that helps enormously with the differences as you rarely write actual sql. thanks all!